# Approximation of sum/average of last n terms in a series

Tags: math

Assume I have a series t_1, t_2,..., t_n,..., and the number is always coming in. I  want to calculate the approximate of sum/average of last t numbers, but without storing those t numbers. The only thing stored is the previous sum/average. What is the appropriate function?

E.g.

```
s_1 = t_1
s_2 = f(t_2, s_1)
s_3 = f(t_3, s_2)
```

The possible function may be like s_2 = t_2 + s_1 * (e ^ -1), but what is the optimal solution?

Note: The window size is fixed. So there is no exact solution, but an approximation, since the number out of the window is not known.

Note 2: Thanks for all the discussion. I know the answer now. It is really trivial, my fault not thinking it well. I will delete this question later. But any way, the answer is, I should assume that the number out of the window is the average. Under this assumption, the new sum is

```
(old average)*(t-1) + new number
```

and the new average is

```
((old average)*(t-1)+(new number))/t
```

Comment: Can you keep track of how many numbers have come in so far?

Comment: A homework question perchance?

Comment: @asimes Yes, you can, since the storage is O(1)

Comment: @Tony Store the running total and the number of items - two numbers is all that is required

Comment: @Ed Heal, No, it is not a homework.

Comment: @Tony - So this is for you work? Seems a rather trivial problem to solve

Comment: @Ed Heal, what is your definition of running total? If you do not store, you cannot minus the one out of the window.

Comment: @Tony - You comment does not make sense. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total

Comment: @Ed Heal, thanks for the link of running total. But no, I am not calculating the running total. The window size is fixed, always the last t numbers.

Comment: @tony - The key word is "approximation"

Comment: BTW `(old average)*(t-1` is the same as the sum of the last `t-1` items. So just keep the running sum and the value t

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring, Yes, please see note 2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this realistically is probably a question for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

but anyway, since you dont mention a programming language, Ill go with C# (with an array). lets call your series 'mySeries':

```
double average=0;
for (int i = 0; i < mySeries.Length; i++)
    average+=mySeries[i]/(i+1);

MessageBox.Show("Here is your average dawg:" + average.ToString());
```